# How do I use the Bootstrap 3 mixins?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, mixins

I'm learning Bootstrap 3 and trying to simply change the color of an H1 tag when the screen size is a desktop.  I want to avoid using device widths in my css, so I was hoping to do something as basic as this but it's not working:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md) {
  h1 {color: #ff0000;}
}
```

I've made sure to have downloaded the compiled bootstrap 3 zip file, which according to the documentation should have these bootstrap specific mixins.  The zip file does not come with a less folder and if I am reading the docs right, the min css file should already be compiled and ready to go with their proprietary less variables.

I've got a simple page that I would hope displays my Hello World in red when being viewed on a desktop, but it does not.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I still need to download the less files from the GitHub project and include those in place of the bootstrap css?

Comment: I usually do `@media screen and (min-width:@screen-md-min){}` without error. If it is compiled, it will not see variables. You will need to download the source (yes - the LESS on GitHub) and then adjust/compile yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the compiled bootstrap 3 file, but the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.0.0) if you want to use and modify the less mixins. See the [github repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for further information.